# Next JS 13 custom nodemon express server socket hangup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

Im working on an application that uses Next Js 13 and has a custom webpack plugin for fileshadowing. Currently Im experiencing an issue with Next JS when I try to build it gets stuck in the step `- info Creating an optimized production build ..`.
When I run my dev server (custom express server & nodemon) I get an unhandled rejection saying there has been a socket hangup.
Here the error code:

The error from the dev server:

```
HTTP 88912: removeSocket 127.0.0.1:64513: writable: false
HTTP 88912: HTTP socket close
Failed to proxy http://127.0.0.1:64513/ Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:711:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:467:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
HTTP 88912: write ret = true
HTTP 88912: outgoing message end.
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:711:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:467:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
Error: Unhandled rejection
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/chaysenrathert/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/frontend/core-shop/server/index.ts:74:17)
    at process.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at process.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at process.emit.sharedData.processEmitHook.installedValue [as emit] (/Users/chaysenrathert/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/frontend/core-shop/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:745:40)
    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)
    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:269:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32) {
  rejection: Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:711:14)
      at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:467:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  }
}
NET 88912: _read
HTTP 88912: SERVER socketOnParserExecute 1003
HTTP 88912: call onSocket 0 0
```

here the `server/indext.ts`

```
/* eslint-disable import/order */
// this file needs to be on top to register module aliases
// we have to disable eslint here to bypass order rule

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
require('dotenv').config()
import initAliases from './initAliases'
initAliases()

import express from 'express'
import next from 'next'
import redirectConfig from '@core/config/redirects'
import redirectUrls from '@core/config/redirects/redirectUrls.json'
import { RedirectUrls } from '@core/config/redirects/types'
import { Environment } from '@core/utils/Environment'
import { logging } from '@core/utils/logging'
import CustomNextRoutes from './CustomNextRoutes'
import HealthCheck from './HealthCheck'
import Redirects from './Redirects'
import requestLogger from './RequestLogger'
import Robots from './Robots'
import Sitemap from './Sitemap'
import { installMemoryLogger } from './debug'
import { removeTrailingSlash } from './middleware'

const DEFAULT_PORT = 3000

const port = Environment.default.getInt('PORT') || DEFAULT_PORT
const dev = Environment.default.isDevelopment
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    // Setup server routes / middlewares
    const server = express()

    // Handle optional slash at end of URL
    server.use(removeTrailingSlash)

    // Setup Health check
    server.use(HealthCheck())
    // Setup sitemap routes
    server.use(Sitemap())
    // Setup custom routes that do not use the default Next.js naming convention
    server.use(CustomNextRoutes(app))

    // Setup legacy URL redirects
    server.use(Redirects(redirectConfig, redirectUrls as RedirectUrls))

    server.use(Robots())

    server.use(requestLogger)

    // Fallback: Process other routes through Next.js
    // Next either finds a matching page with the route name, or returns the 404 error page
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(port, () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    logging.error(ex)
    process.exit(1)
  })

// Global error handling for everything outside of express / next.js
process.on('unhandledRejection', (rejection) => {
  logging.error(new Error('Unhandled rejection'), { rejection })
})

process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
  logging.error(error)
})

// Debug memory logger
if (Environment.default.getBoolean('MEMORY_LOGGING_ENABLED')) {
  installMemoryLogger()
}
```

Im not sure where this error is coming from as the stack trace is not very clear. Any chance anyone has an idea about how I can find the isue or how to debug this to see where this issue issue coming from?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- I enabled NODE_DEBUG and checked the logs but no helpful infromation came from this
- tried logging inside the custom webpack plugin, no result